# DRF- Creating new objects from nested representation raises TypeError

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have the following two models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.CharField(
        max_length=129,
        unique=True,
    )
    user_article = models.ManyToManyField(
        Article,
        through="UserArticle",
    )
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='null')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_id
```

and

```
class Article(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(editable=False, unique=True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(
        Company,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='article_company_id',
    )
    articleType = models.ForeignKey(
        ArticleType,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name='type',
    )    
    date_inserted = models.DateField()    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.uuid
```

which are modeled with a many-to-many relationship, using this through model:

```
class UserArticle(models.Model):    
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, to_field='user_id',
                             on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, to_field='uuid',
                                 on_delete=models.PROTECT,)
    posted_as = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True),)
    post_date = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = "core_user_articles"
```

Here's my view:

```
class BatchUserArticleList(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = UserArticle.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BatchUserArticleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = BatchUserArticleSerializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return response.Response({'Message': 'POST failed',
                                  'Errors': serializer.errors},
                                 status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        self.perform_create(serializer)  # equal to serializer.save()
        return response.Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

The problem I'm facing is when I want to POST data, of the following format, in the M2M table:

```
{
    "posted_as": ["news"],
    "post_date": "2020-05-26",
    "user": "jhtpo9jkj4WVQc0000GXk0zkkhv7u",
    "article": [
        "11111111",
        "22222222"
    ]
}
```

As I'm not passing an exact mapping of a `user` or `article` entity (I'm only passing the uids and not the rest of the model fields), my serializer fields **cannot** be the following (I'm getting validation errors):

```
user = UserSerializer()
article = ArticleSerializer()
```

So the `serializer` I'm using is the following:

```
class BatchUserArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField()
    article = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.UUIDField()
    )  
    class Meta:
        model = UserArticle
        fields = '__all__'

    def validate(self, data):    
        post_date = data['post_date']
        if post_date != date.today():
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                'post_date: post_date is not valid',
            )
        return data

    def create(self, validated_data):
        posted_as = list(map(lambda item: item, validated_data['posted_as']))
        post_date = validated_data['post_date']
        user = validated_data['user']
        list_of_articles = validated_data['article']
        user_object = User.objects.get(user_id=user)
        articles_objects = list(map(lambda res: Article.objects.get(uuid=res), list_of_articles))

        user_articles_to_insert = list(map(
            lambda article: UserArticle(
                posted_as=posted_as,
                post_date=post_date,
                article=article,
                user=user_object),
        articles_objects)

        try:
            created_user_articles = UserArticle.objects.bulk_create(user_articles_to_insert) 
            # returning only the first result since create() expects only one object
            return created_user_articles[0] 
        except Exception as error:
            raise Exception('Something went wrong: {0}'.format(error))
```

This seems to work fine as I can see my data being correctly inserted in the `UserArticle` table:

```
id | posted_as | post_date | user | article
1  | news      | 2020-05-26 | jhtpo9jkj4WVQc0000GXk0zkkhv7u | 11111111
2  | news      | 2020-05-26 | jhtpo9jkj4WVQc0000GXk0zkkhv7u | 22222222
```

However, I get the following error in the response:

```
  File "core/views.py", line 430, in create
    return response.Response(serializer.data, status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 562, in data
    ret = super().data
  File "python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 260, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 529, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/fields.py", line 1692, in to_representation
    return [self.child.to_representation(item) if item is not None else None for item in data]
TypeError: 'Article' object is not iterable
```

How can I serialize this nested representation? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `data` is  a*single* object, hence you can not use `for item in data`...

Comment: But this is an error within the `drf` framework itself. What have I done wrong and caused this?

Answer (score 1):

you should override representation method of your Serializer because after calling create method call to_representation func to return data to client and because you change user serializer and article serializer this method cannot return true data

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    return {'result':{'id':instance.id}}
```

Comment: I made it work by adding `serializer = UserResourceSerializer(value)
                                         return serializer.data` in the `to_representation` method